# What is the advantage of defining a macro in the following snippet?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose the following piece of **C** code:

```
  #define SOME_MACRO(m)  \
  void (*f)(m);          \
  unsigned int a;        \
  int *self;
```

and then a struct that does

```
typedef struct _Str {
   SOME_MACRO(whatever)
   char sthg[2];
} STR;
```

My question is: what is the purpose of this design choice? It's not that we're saving time in indirection, for instance. Is there anything more here than an attempt at modularizing the code of `_STR`?

Answer (score 3):

My project uses that pattern to ensure that certain methods/members are available in every project class (e.g. for marshalling). Again without more examples there's no way to confirm but that is my theory.

Comment: Rob, are you talking about C?

Comment: In our case, C++, but the same idea could apply to C, depending on the macro... is it used in multiple structures?

Comment: Actually, given that it's C, this could be a kind of rudimentary polymorphism... see "self" for example.

Answer (score 0):

SOME_MACRO(m) translates to a function pointer to a function returning nothing which takes in one argument of type `m`, and also a unsigned int and a pointer to int. I believe the design reasons behind something like this is highly case-specific and without having more elaborate example of the code I would believe this is used for modularizing the code as you mention.

Answer (score -1):

just from the code that you given ,i also can't make a explanation but it's seems some simple ,so that ,i think ,it's just a test macro by a new programmer because the meaning of "SOME_MACRO"=some macro test codes...

Comment: I think you've missed the point; the OP has probably removed some details particular to their work, but is asking about the technique in general.